# How to plot three different arrays in a 3d surface plot

Tags: matlab

I have three different arrays `a`, `b`, `c`. I want to plot them in Matlab where `c` in the z axis and `a` and `b` in the x and y axis.

I mean I have a formula `f(a, b)` which I want to plot against `a` and `b`.

Comment: Please show an example of your data as well as an illustration of the desired result.

Comment: @Dev-iL: Thanks. I mean I have a formula $f(\alpha, \beta)$ which I want to plot against $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I assume you tried the obvious [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) function. How did that fail to meet your requirements? Did you try any other plotting functions?

Comment: If you want points, you can just use `plot3` or `scatter3`?

Comment: Related post with examples: stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried meshgrid?

```
[a, b] = meshgrid(minA:stepA:maxA, minB:stepB:maxB);
c = myFunction(a,b);
surf(a,b,c);
```

Where a and b are in the ranges (minA,maxA) and (minB,maxB), respectively.